# Oracle trigger compiles but fails on insert

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have the following trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_RESUME_AFTER_UPDATE
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON RESUME
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :new.modified_date := SYSTIMESTAMP;
END;
```

Which compiles

```
TRIGGER TRG_RESUME_AFTER_UPDATE compiled
```

However when I try an insert I get the following error:

```
Error at Command Line : 11 Column : 8
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'D.TRG_RESUME_AFTER_UPDATE' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PL/SQL object can "compile" but still have errors.  It sounds like whatever client program you are using may not be giving you proper feedback.  (In SQLPlus, it should say "Trigger created with compilation errors".)

In any case, the thing to do is query USER_ERRORS to find out what the errors are.  Since the trigger is so simple, I would guess that either `modified_date` doesn't exist in the table, or it is a datatype that a timestamp can't be implicitly converted to.  If it is a `DATE`, it would be more appropriate to use `SYSDATE` than `SYSTIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Good call Dave was SYSDATE instead of timeStamp